# Altering the Sort Filter in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I live in Australia and when I'm putting in dates, I place the date, followed by month then the year. However when I am filtering/sorting my spreadsheet it's coming up incorrectly.

How do I edit this sort field so that I can get it to filter by year, month and then date (but how I write it)?

Comment: Thanks for your post Kara. In order for us to help you properly, it would be very helpful to have a shared Google Document. Please share only those things you want to share with us and the rest of the world !!

Comment: ... and if you can't share a spreadsheet, a screenshot showing the sort/filter field, and your problem, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your sheet locale is Australia, your dates are dd/mmm/yyyy format order and you are using New Google Sheets the sorting should be 'sensible'.

Answer (score 0):

The default Google spreadsheets format for dates is MM/DD/YYYY. This means that if you use DD/MM/YYYY it will be considered as text, not as a date.

My suggestion is that you enter the dates as MM/DD/YYYY so you will be able to filter, order and properly perform any other date/time actions. For presentation purposes you can always change the format to DD/MM/YYYY once the dates are entered.

Hope this helps